# XPath Query to find Specific Element Fails

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am attempting to parse some XML data using XPath queries in C#. But my query is not successfully finding the element I am looking for (it finds nothing).

Whats wrong with my XPath query? Is my syntax for `following-sibling` incorrect or something? How can I edit my XPath to find the correct `value` element?

```
<attributes>
  <real>
    <name>cover rl</name>
    <value>89.87414122</value>
  </real>
  <real>
    <name>pit depth</name>
    <value>2.35620671</value> <!-- This is the value I need -->
  </real>
<attributes>
```

My XPath query that fails:

```
ns:attributes/real/name[text() = 'pit depth']/following-sibling::value
```

Comment: Please adding language and actual code sample - all languages/libraries have they own ways of dealing with namespace prefixes/declarations. (Also unclear why do you even need one for given XML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Mostly get rid of the spurious `ns:` namespace prefix.  Also note that your sample input XML should end with a closing `</attributes>` element rather than another opening `<attributes>` element

So, this XPath:

```
/attributes/real/name[. = 'pit depth']/following-sibling::value
```

Will yield:

```
<value>2.35620671</value>
```

per your request.

If you only want the contents of the `value` element:

```
/attributes/real/name[. = 'pit depth']/following-sibling::value/text()
```

Will yield:

```
2.35620671
```